# Solving differential equation by specifying jacobian pattern

Tags: matlab, ode, numerics, numerical-modelling, jacobian

This is a follow up to my previous question posted [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/36290/how-to-set-up-the-differential-equation-system-to-speed-up-computation?noredirect=1#comment72218_36290)

I'm trying to construct the sparsity pattern of the jacobian matrix to speed up the computation of a large system of odes. The following is the code in which I am trying to set up the jpattern in
`odeset` for a toy model in MATLAB.

```
global mat1 mat2
mat1=[ 
       1    -2     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0;
       0     1    -2     1     0     0     0     0     0     0;
       0     0     1    -2     1     0     0     0     0     0;
       0     0     0     1    -2     1     0     0     0     0;
       0     0     0     0     1    -2     1     0     0     0;
       0     0     0     0     0     1    -2     1     0     0;
       0     0     0     0     0     0     1    -2     1     0;
       0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1    -2     1;
       ];

mat2 = [
        1    -1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0;
        0     1    -1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0;
        0     0     1    -1     0     0     0     0     0     0;
        0     0     0     1    -1     0     0     0     0     0;
        0     0     0     0     1    -1     0     0     0     0;
        0     0     0     0     0     1    -1     0     0     0;
        0     0     0     0     0     0     1    -1     0     0;
        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1    -1     0;
        ];



x0 = [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]';
tspan = 0:0.01:5;

f0 = fun(0, x0);
joptions = struct('diffvar', 2, 'vectvars', 1, 'thresh', 1e-8, 'fac', []);
J = odenumjac(@fun,{0 x0}, f0, joptions); 
sparsity_pattern = sparse(J~=0.);
options = odeset('Stats', 'on', 'JPattern', sparsity_pattern);

ttic = tic();
[t, sol]  =  ode15s(@(t,x) fun(t,x), tspan , x0); %, options);
ttoc = toc(ttic)
fprintf('runtime %f seconds ...\n', ttoc)
plot(t, sol)

function f = fun(t,x)
global mat1 mat2

fprintf('size of x: %d %d\n', size(x))

f(1,1) = 0;
f(2:9,1) = mat1*x + mat2*x;
f(10,1) = 2*(x(end-1) - x(end));
end
```

When I run the code, I notice that the size of the vector `x` in `fun` changes for the second iteration
because of which an error occurs.

```
size of x: 10 1
size of x: 10 10
```

Error:

```
Unable to perform assignment because the size of the left side is 8-by-1 and the size of the right side is 8-by-10.

Error in Untitled>fun (line 47)
f(2:9,1) = mat1*x + mat2*x;

Error in odenumjac (line 143)
    Fdel = feval(F,Fargs_expanded{:});

Error in Untitled (line 31)
J = odenumjac(@fun,{0 x0}, f0, joptions);
```

Suggestions on how to fix this error will be really helpful.

EDIT:

I've tried to vectorize `f` in `fun` and also set `vectvars`=2 to vectorize the jacobian calculation.

```
global mat1 mat2
mat1=[ 
       1    -2     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0;
       0     1    -2     1     0     0     0     0     0     0;
       0     0     1    -2     1     0     0     0     0     0;
       0     0     0     1    -2     1     0     0     0     0;
       0     0     0     0     1    -2     1     0     0     0;
       0     0     0     0     0     1    -2     1     0     0;
       0     0     0     0     0     0     1    -2     1     0;
       0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1    -2     1;
       ];

mat2 = [
        1    -1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0;
        0     1    -1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0;
        0     0     1    -1     0     0     0     0     0     0;
        0     0     0     1    -1     0     0     0     0     0;
        0     0     0     0     1    -1     0     0     0     0;
        0     0     0     0     0     1    -1     0     0     0;
        0     0     0     0     0     0     1    -1     0     0;
        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1    -1     0;
        ];



x0 = [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]';
tspan = 0:0.01:5;

f0 = fun(0, x0);
joptions = struct('diffvar', 2, 'vectvars', 2, 'thresh', 1e-8, 'fac', []);
J = odenumjac(@fun,{0 x0}, f0, joptions); 
sparsity_pattern = sparse(J~=0.);
options = odeset('Stats', 'on', 'JPattern', sparsity_pattern, 'Vectorized', 'on');

ttic = tic();
[t, sol]  =  ode15s(@(t,x) fun(t,x), tspan , x0, options);
ttoc = toc(ttic)
fprintf('runtime %f seconds ...\n', ttoc)
plot(t, sol)

function f = fun(t,x)
global mat1 mat2
f(1,:) = 0;
f(2:9,:) = mat1*x + mat2*x;
f(10,:) = 2*(x(end-1) - x(end));
end
```

However, there is a problem again when `vectvars` = 2 in joptions and/or   'Vectorized', 'on' in options defined for ode15s.

```
Unable to perform assignment because the size of the left side is 8-by-1 and the size of the right side is 8-by-10.

Error in cse_11_5_20>fun (line 44)
f(2:9,:) = mat1*x + mat2*x;

Error in odenumjac (line 143)
    Fdel = feval(F,Fargs_expanded{:});

Error in cse_11_5_20 (line 31)
J = odenumjac(@fun,{0 x0}, f0, joptions);
```

Comment: This question seems to be more about programming than computational science.

Comment: @nicoguaro Do you suggest I migrate this to stackoverflow? If this is not the right place to post this question, could one of the moderators consider migrating my post to stackoverflow?

Comment: I am not sure if it is suitable there.

Comment: Regarding your code, ``mat1*x + mat2*x`` is a vector with length 10 and you are assigning it to one with length 8, ``f(2:9, 1)``.

Comment: @nicoguaro Thank you. mat1 is of size (8, 10) and x is of size (10,1) so the resulting vector is of size 8 x 1. This works fine in the 1st iteration . In the second iteration, x is of size (10, 10). This results in a  matrix of size 8 x 10 (here is the issue and this happens while using odenumjac). I'm not sure why the size of x changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`odenumjac` calls your function in a vectorized manner it seems, and your function is not vectorized. You can easily change that by changing the second index of f in your function to `:` instead of `1`, for instance:
`f(10,:) = 2*(x(end-1,:) - x(end,:));`

I thought the setting `joptions.vectvars=1` would not allow the vectorised call (see one of your other questions). I realize that this is actually not the case, you should instead set it to `[]` (empty). If you want to vectorize the Jacobian calculation, set it to `2`. You can type `open odenumjac`in the Matlab console to access the function file and read its documentation.

More info on vectorization can be found here:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html

Comment: Thanks a lot again. Setting `vectvars` = [ ]  solved my problem and for my real system the computation time reducted from ~2 hours to ~7 minutes . But I am still facing problem in using the `vectorized` form of both jacobian and the function `f` in `fun` . Could you please have a look edit 2? I looked the function file of `odenumjac`, unfortunately I couldn't understand the documentation provided for `vectvars`.

Comment: @Natasha this may come from the first line `f(1,:) = 0` which may result in the second dimension of f being initialised as 1. I would try initialising `f` properly at the start of `fun`, for example with `f = zeros('like',x)`. Maybe you also need to play with the value of `vectvars`. For that you need to look at the `odenumjac` function to see how it works.

Comment: `f = zeros('like', x)` gives size(f) = [1,1]. I tried all three options [1] [2] [] for `vectvars`.  The simulation fails when I set 'Vectorized', 'on' when `vectvars`=[]. I couldn't understand the details given for `vectvars` in odenumjac function :/

Comment: Hi.. f = zeros(size(x), 'like', x); helps!

Comment: Oh yes, looks like I misread Matlab's documentation ! So does this solve your problem ?